# 1120: Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am getting this error message when I try to access a button movieclip from inside a videoPlayer movieclip.  They are not nested.  When the videoPlayer button is clicked the buttons tween to the bottom of the screen out of the way whilst the videoPlayer sits in their previous location.  On closing the videoPlayer I would like the buttons to tween back in from the right of the screen but I get the following error message "1120: Access of undefined property TweenMax.from(btn1, 3, {x:450, y:209.1, ease:Back.easeOut});.  My question is what would I use in as3 to access control of the buttons so I can tween them on closing the videoPlayer movieclip.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
The flvPlayer script:-

stop();

closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeVid)
closeBtn.buttonMode = true;

function closeVid(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    video.stop();
    gotoAndStop(1);
    TweenMax.from(btn1, 3, {x:450, y:209.1, ease:Back.easeOut});
}

**********************************************************************

The script from outside the videoPlayer or scene1:-

import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var numberOfButtons:Number = 3

var startX:Number;
var startY:Number;

var currentButton:MovieClip

for (var i:int = 1; i <= numberOfButtons; i++)
    {

        this["btn"+i].buttonMode = true;
        this["btn"+i].mouseChildren = false;
        this["btn"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, doRollover)
        this["btn"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, doRollout)
        this["btn"+i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showbtnContent);
    }

function doRollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenMax.to(this[e.target.name], 1, {scaleX:1.1, scaleY:1.1, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
}

// This function handles the Rollout event  
function doRollout(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    TweenMax.to(this[e.target.name], 1, {scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
}

function showbtnContent(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    currentButton = this[e.target.name]
    switch (currentButton)
    {
        case btn1:
        TweenMax.from(audioPlayer, 1, {x:449, y:-112, ease:Back.easeOut});
        audioPlayer.gotoAndStop(2);
        audioPlayer.parent.setChildIndex(audioPlayer, audioPlayer.parent.numChildren-1);
        break;

        case btn2:
        TweenMax.from(mcGallery, 1, {x:450, y:300, scaleX:1, scaleY:1, ease:Back.easeOut});
        mcGallery.gotoAndStop(2);
        mcGallery.parent.setChildIndex(mcGallery, mcGallery.parent.numChildren-1);
        break;

        case btn3:
        TweenMax.to(btn1, 20, {x:450, y:777.1, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
        TweenMax.to(btn2, 16, {x:450, y:777.1, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
        TweenMax.to(btn3, 12, {x:450, y:777.1, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
        TweenMax.from(flvPlayer, 3, {x:1060, y:280, ease:Back.easeOut});
        flvPlayer.gotoAndStop(2);
        flvPlayer.parent.setChildIndex(flvPlayer, flvPlayer.parent.numChildren-1);
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: `this["btn+i"]` makes me cringe.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `gotoAndStop(1);` it moves to the first frame, where the btn1,btn2 and btn3 did not exist.

fixing it will be tough, because you'll need to move the timeline into a separate MovieClip from the MovieClip or Sprite that is holding the buttons, so that this does not happen.